# socket.io authentification not working on first connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, jwt, node-webkit

I have a NodeWebkit client which connects to a nodejs server using the socket.io library (JavaScript).

The client launches the connect procedure on the application start but the server does not acknoledge any connections... Though the client's socket has the connected attribute to "true".

You should know that I am using socketio-jwt to authentificate the connection.
Github: https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt

I know that the connection does work in a way because if I add :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(){console.log("hello");})
```

It prints hello !

So it seems that event though the connection is somehow made it doesn't want to do the auth part with the library, resulting in... Well... Nothing.

But that's not all !!
Because **if I reboot the app (not the server) then the auth works most of the time !** It acts like a race condition... But I dont see how it could possibly be one... Every line of code is geting executed appart of the success callback of authentification.

I tried connecting to a remote server and on my localhost.
I also tried with an other library of socket auth but I've got the same probleme.

This is the server code:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var socketioJwt = require('socketio-jwt');

io.sockets.on('connection', socketioJwt.authorize({
    secret: 'some secret',
    timeout: 15000 // 15 seconds to send the authentication message
})).on('authenticated', function (socket) {

   console.log('[Info]: A user connected to socket = ', socket.decoded_token);

});
});



http.listen(5000, function () {
      console.log('listening on *:5000');
});
```

And now the client code:

```
this.socket = io.connect('http://' + that.hostName +':' + that.port);     
var token = jwt.sign({email: "someEail", pwd: "somePwd"}, fromServerSecret); 

this.socket.on('connect', function () {
    that.socket.emit('authenticate', {token: token}) //send the jwt
            .on('authenticated', function () {

                console.log("[Info]: Socket login successfull");

            })
            .on('unauthorized', function (msg) {
                console.log("[Warning]: Socket unauthorized: " + JSON.stringify(msg.data));
                throw new Error(msg.data.type);
            });
});
```

The server side log "A user connected to socket" is never shown.
If you have an idear ! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Why is there a 'that' on socket.emit (client)? I think you should handle it within the same instance of socket.io - using same 'this' as above

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first line of my function that don't appear in the code above is "var that = this". I save the function's scope at the start.      So on the first level I can use "this" because it is the root scope. Then I'm in the callback of the ".on" and the scope is the callback's scope.       That's why I saved the scope in "that" at the start. Though I checked if the socket was still avaible through "that" and it is. Hope that what I'm saying still makes sense after all thoses "this" and "that". ;-)

Comment: That makes sense. Then maybe you should try nesting the sockets on the server side instead of chaining them, the same way you did on client side.